# Checkbox appears in one place but the checking functionality is a few pixels to the left

Tags: html, css, wordpress, checkbox

I have a checkbox in a registration form, I can't check the box itself but if I click a few pixels to the left, the checkbox is checked. 
looks like a CSS problem? what could be causing this?

this is the HTML code for it

```
<input type="checkbox" id="termsConditions" name="termsConditions" style="">
```

Nothing looks suspicious in the CSS, not that I've changed anything, it's the default.

[image]

Comment: This is likely a CSS issue but I would need to inspect the site to tell you what’s going on. Can you include a link to the site?

Comment: this is a link to the stagin website not the live one but it has the same issue: https://boxli.mystagingwebsite.com 
the problem is only in the pop up registration form, and only in the other language not in the english version

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I’m afraid I don’t see the checkbox. Can you tell me how to find it?

Comment: here's a screen shot: http://imgur.com/a/cf8TG  click the highlighted text, you'll get a popup, the checkbox is the one with the longer text.

Comment: Hmm, it displays in English for me and the is no issue clicking the checkbox http://imgur.com/akxwlC6 One thing, though, is that you are missing a <label> for that checkbox :)

Comment: Can you try the other language? you have to switch languages and then click the register button (in the other language not english)